# Virtual PC is forcing me to use old password and not connecting to network

Tags: windows, virtualization

I am using Windows Virtual PC under Windows 7 Ultimate. My VM starts up fine and goes to the login screen, but when I try to enter my current network password it says it is incorrect. However once I enter an older password I can log on fine. The problem though is once I try to access network folders I get verification errors. The VM does not seem to recognize either the network or that my password is changed. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by incorrect network setup of either the Virtual PC Server or the running virtual pc.

I assume it is a domain login.

You need to fix your network settings.

Comment: Yes, it is a domain, and I assumed it was a network issue. I have tried all the network settings I could think of...

Comment: Networking is a mess in Virtual PC - it can be disturbed by Firewalls. Even having multiple network interfaces can cause trouble sometimes. I've quit using it since VirtualBox works a lot better (without the networking trouble).